# SSH and X11 forwarding strangeness

Tags: ssh, x11

Got a problem; I've got a server were I have been using X11 forwarding for a long time, without any problems. Now; a strange has occurred.

If I login using  `ssh -X -Y user@device`, connection is successful. If xterm/xeyes starts, the appropriate window appears on my computer.

If I start emacs or gwenview, nothing happens...

Running `ssh -vvv -X -Y user@device`and starting xterm, this is logged.

```
debug3: receive packet: type 90 
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 3 win 65536 max 16384 
debug1: client_request_x11: request from ::1 34772 
debug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK 
debug3: fd 8 is O_NONBLOCK 
debug1: channel 1: new [x11] 
debug1: confirm x11 
debug3: send packet: type 91 
debug2: channel 1: rcvd adjust 44420 
debug2: channel 1: rcvd adjust 49152 
debug2: channel 1: rcvd adjust 49152
```

then the xterm shows up.

Starting emacs this is logged;

```
debug3: receive packet: type 90
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 3 win 65536 max 16384
debug1: client_request_x11: request from ::1 34776
debug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 8 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [x11]
debug1: confirm x11
debug3: send packet: type 91
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 1: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 1: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 1: obuf empty
debug2: channel 1: close_write
debug2: channel 1: output drain -> closed
debug1: channel 1: FORCE input drain
debug2: channel 1: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 1: send eof
debug3: send packet: type 96
debug2: channel 1: input drain -> closed
debug2: channel 1: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug3: channel 1: will not send data after close
debug3: receive packet: type 90
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 4 win 65536 max 16384
debug1: client_request_x11: request from ::1 34778
debug2: fd 9 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 9 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 2: new [x11]
debug1: confirm x11
debug3: send packet: type 91
debug3: channel 1: will not send data after close
debug3: channel 1: will not send data after close
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 1: rcvd close
debug3: channel 1: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 1: is dead
debug2: channel 1: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 1: free: x11, nchannels 3
debug3: channel 1: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 5/6 cc -1)
  #1 x11 (t4 r3 i3/0 o3/0 fd 8/8 cc -1)
  #2 x11 (t7 r4 i0/0 o0/0 fd 9/9 cc -1)
```

This then repeats two more times, then nothing.

Emacs is compiled with x support.

At this point Im drawing a blank; x11 forwarding works (xterm works) but emacs/gwenview does not.  :(

Is it an SSH, X11 or something else error?

BR/Patrik

Comment: users have on occasion complained about emacs not working possibly due to font or x11 protocol (or possibly also gnome or gtk?) reasons but I've never chased those issues very far

Comment: Guess: You updated emacs and gwenview, and the new versions use Gnome etc. Toolkit bindings, and these bindings use OpenGL stuff  that is not part of the X protocol, and not forwarded via ssh. Options: (1) Downgrade apps, (2) compile apps yourself with other Toolkit bindings (if possible), (3) use some other way to forward graphical apps (RDP, VNC, ...). With emacs, you can also always run it in another ssh terminal in text mode (`emacs -nw`).

Comment: Ended up removing all 'apt-get purge libx11.* libqt.*' [https://askubuntu.com/questions/73219/remove-packages-to-tranform-ubuntu-desktop-to-server] , and all programs depending on it. Then reinstalling..

Answer (score 0):

As @dirkt indicated, most likely it was a version mismatch between the components used. The solution was to remove all X11 and QT based applications, then reinstalling them.

Would have been good if some logs would have been produced.